# How to aggregate a custom model function when it's not a part of the database in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a project that I need to open and close tickets. So, this is my Ticket model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    issue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', blank=True, null=True, related_name="tickets")
    date_opened = models.DateTimeField('Date opened')
    date_closed = models.DateTimeField('Date closed', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.issue

    def time_to_solve(self):
        time_to_solve = self.date_opened - self.date_closed
        out = [ time_to_solve.hours//60 ]
        return '{:d} hours'.format(*out)
```

and I want to calculate the average of the time difference between `date_opened` and `date_closed`.

In my views.py I have created a view :

```
class Dashboard(ListView):
    model = Ticket
    template_name = 'assets/dashboard.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Dashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['time_to_complete'] = Q(status__contains='closed')).aggregate(time_opened = Avg('time_to_solve'))
        return context
```

Unfortunately it does not work because "time_to_solve" is not a part of the database.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can only aggregate model fields, but it's not hard to do that in python:

```
tickets = Ticket.objects.filter(status__contains='closed') 
average = sum(map(lambda x: x.time_to_solve(), tickets)) / tickets.count()
```

In this case `time_to_solve` should return something like the number of seconds and you can format that as you need right after that.

Depending on the number of tickets, this might not be the fastest solution. If performance are an issue you might want to use some kind of denormalization.

Comment: I thought that I could use django without much python but now I see it's unavoidable. It's not that I do not enjoy python programming (that I do a lot actually) but I am trying to shrink the learning curve. If this is the proper way to do this, I am going to try it right away.

Comment: I am getting "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'". Any ideas ?

Comment: @RobDel That's because `time_to_solve` returns a string. You should write it as simply `return self.date_closed - self.date_opened`, that way you get a timedelta, which you can use to compute the average (you can add and divide timedeltas). Then you'll just need to format the resulting average as a string.

Comment: As I said, time_to_solve should return a number (I'd use seconds) and you can format it later.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that directly with the ORM. You can do it in Python but that will retrieve all closed Ticket rows from the database. If you want to do it in SQL you'll need to express your query as [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/). If you're using PostgreSQL you might find this useful : [Working with Dates and Times in PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL).

Comment: It's actually MySQL but there must be a way to do this.. it's very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer from a friend in #irc - django on Freenode:

```
average = Ticket.objects.extra(
            select={ 'date_difference': 'AVG(time_to_sec(TIMEDIFF(date_closed,date_opened)))'}).first().date_difference
        context['average'] = "{:.2f}".format(average/86400)
        return context
```

This way it returns the average with 2 decimals accuracy and does everything in the database level so it's much lighter to run than fetching all rows.